# How can I debug a program that starts but appears to do nothing?

Tags: c++, debugging, ubuntu, terminal

I currently have 2 virtual machines running, one is a server and one is a client. They are both running Ubuntu. I created a C++ program to connect to a MYSQL server. When i open up a terminal in the server VM, the c++ program compiles and runs PERFECTLY!

BUT, when I try to run it on the client, it wont work at all. The code compiles perfectly fine but when i type "**./main**" to start the program, NOTHING comes up. It's just a blank screen. I totally do not get why this is happening. The code is exactly the same on both the client and the server, but for some reason, it wont display ANY of my code when I run it on the client side.  Below are pictures to show what i mean

Here is a link to view a screenshot of what I am talking about (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG3QM.jpg).  In the first picture, I compile the program, which compiles fine. I then run the program but NOTHING outputs to the screen.

The second picture shows the program being ran on the server and shows what is suppose to be output on the screen after the initial **./main** command

What should I do to find out what's going wrong?

Comment: As David Schwartz suggests, add print-logging statements to see how far the program is getting. However, my ESP is working: most likely, your mysql server is configured to allow connections from certain IP addresses and not from others.

Comment: When you get compiler warnings, that doesn't count as compiling "perfectly fine."

Comment: You don't include any code, so it's hard for any of us to guess what's wrong.  But generally I think you should learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Thank you Russell.  I think it was hanging due to trying to connect to the mysql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add logging to your program or run it under `strace` to figure out where it's getting stuck or what it's waiting for.

At the most basic level, you add logging by adding log statements. Say your code looks like this:

```
a();
b();
c();
output_stuff();
```

Temporarily change it to:

```
cout << "about to do a" << endl;
a();
cout << "about to do b" << endl;
b();
cout << "about to do c" << endl;
c();
cout << "done with c" << endl;
output_stuff();
```

Then see what messages you get. If you don't get "about to do a" then it's a constructor for a global object or process initialization that's hanging. If you get "about to do a" but not "about to do b", then it's `a()` that's hanging. And so on.

Comment: What could it possibly be waiting for if the code is identical across both platforms? Sorry, im new to linux so im not familiar with "strace"

Comment: There's no way to know without knowing what the code does. Perhaps, for example, it tries to resolve a name and one machine has working DNS and one doesn't. Perhaps it's something else entirely. You won't know until you look. (What does the program do before it outputs anything? That's what's getting stuck.)

Comment: got it thank you. I found out it was hanging when trying to connect to he server.

Answer (score 2):

Compile with "-g -ggdb" and run it in a debugger:

$ cgdb --args ./main your_args

When it blocks pres Ctrl-C and type "bt". That will tell you where the program stopped.
There might be a gazillion things blocking your code (you use external stuff, like the db).

Give us some code to analyze. We can't help without specifics.

BTW: The fact that it compiles doesn't mean it will run flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Build your program with debug symbols enabled (GCC -g option)

```
$ cat infinite.cpp 
void infinite()
{
    for(;;)
    {
    }
}

int main()
{
    infinite();
}
$ g++ -g infinite.cpp
```

Run your program:

```
$ ./a.out
```

Open new terminal session

Find out what is PID of your program

```
$ ps x | grep a.out
7817 pts/3    R+     0:08 ./a.out
```

Run gdb and attach it to your program (sudo if you get permission error):

```
$ gdb
...
(gdb) attach 7817
Attaching to process 7817
...
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
infinite () at infinite.cpp:3
3       for(;;)
(gdb) backtrace
#0  infinite () at infinite.cpp:3
#1  0x0000000000400513 in main () at infinite.cpp:10
```

Use the debugger to inspect at what point of execution is your program, set breakpoints, inspect state of your program (perhaps one of loop counters is unsigned integer and overflows, etc.)